# jquery: repeat foreach loop

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach, repeat

I want to create a loop that repeats itself unlimited with a timer, say (1000)

example:

```
1
2
3

1
2
3

1
2
3
```

with unlimited repeats.

Comment: Can you rephrase? I have no idea what it is you're asking.

Comment: i have a json array that contains some urls for some cameras, i want to put each url inside <applet> tag, so each 10s the camera will change to another till previewing all cameras, and then start again from first one, that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(
        function()
        {
             $('.handler').html(i + "<br />");
             i = (++i) % 3;
        }
        , 1000);
    }
);
```

I guess that should do it...

Comment: can i skip the delay before the first element ? as when I increased the time, it appears a little bit delayed

Comment: Yes, you may change setInterval to setTimeout... But they have different behaviors...

Comment: yes, i got it .. thanks at all

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as

```
function loop()
{
    for(var i = 0, t = 100; i < t, i++)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

setInterval(loop, 1000);
```